# Facebook connect API in PHP redirected to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a situation with the Facebook PHP API

```
<?php
$fb_ = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'MY_APPID',
    'secret' => 'MY_SECRET'
)); 
$userId = $fb_->getUser();
$errorMessage = null;

if ($userId) {
    try {
        $user_ = $fb_->api('/me');
        if (isset($user_['error_code'])) {
            $errorMessage = isset($user_['error_msg']) ? self::$user_['error_msg'] : 'An unknown error occurred';
            $errorMessage .= ' (' . $user_['error_code'] . ')';
            $user_ = null;
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $user_ = null;
    }
}

if (!$user_)  {
    $loginUrl = $fb_->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,publish_actions',
        'next' => 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
    ));
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Connect!</a>';
} 
?>
```

My problem is: When I click on "Connect!" I'm redirected to the facebook main page. Any idea?

Comment: Including the URL to where you are being redirected would be helpful. The URL that you get is intended to take you to the Facebook login page. That is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: well if I click on the link I'm redirected here => https://www.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

The dialog url is structured like that :

```
$loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
                . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirectUrl . "&state="
                . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=" . $scope;
```

Echo your $loginUrl and check if the string is a correct url string AND if the strucure is the same.

Comment: here is what I get: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=myApikey&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_location but when I click on it I'm just redirected to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. It looks like I was using an old version of Facebook with the getSession that is deprecated.